# finding a pattern in string python

Tags: python

I have a very  noisy string input and I am trying to clean it..

So, a part of the noisy string can be something like:

```
"big $price chair, 5x10"
```

Now removing symbols and other stuff are done!
But I also want to remove

```
  5x10
```

for this I did this:

```
 def remove_numerics(self,string):
    return ' '.join([term for term in string.split() if not term[0].isdigit()])
```

Which solved this case

but if my string is:

```
    "big $price chair, x10"
```

Then it fails?
what is a good pythonic way to solve this case also.
many thanks.

Comment: So you want to remove all "words" of the form NUMBERSxNUMBERS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
re.sub(r'\b[\dx]+\b', '', "big $price chair, 5x10")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r', \d*x\d+', '', old_string)
```

Comment: +1. Minor nitpick: you should never name variables after python builtins. Change `str` to something else.

Comment: @JoelCornett thanks... been writing C# all week... switched it the wrong way >.<